# Express-session cause heroku app to throw internal server error

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

App was totally working locally however after deployment via heroku it started to throw internal server error. Just one time app worked via heroku and then again it started to give internal server error. Then i tried to find the source of error and i found the express-session is crashing my app when it is deployed via heroku.

Edit: App doesn't crash in the middle of the process, it doesn't totally work. No path is working. Every path throws internal server error because of express-session.

[Server Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMU11.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you share the error message that you get?

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i forgot that i still have this question. I solved the issue. Problem was the session secret. I didn't realize that my .env file is in gitignore file and session was not taking secret from .env so i added a heroku config, named SECRET and that's the solution.